# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' thingspeak

Tags: javascript, api

```js
function updateButt(){
    fetch("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1238918/fields/1.json?api_key=XXXXXXXX&results=1")
    .then (response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then (data => {
        console.log(data.feeds);
        const result = data.feeds.map(waterLevel =>{
            return waterLevel.field1 + "cm"
        }).join("");
        document.getElementById("1b").innerHTML = result;
        console.log(result+" DONE");
    }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I'm suddenly receiving this error, I have no idea what it is because I only use the code above from the internet and the thing is working for the past 5 months, suddenly this happens.

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1238918/fields/1.json?api_key=XXXXXX&results=1' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: I suggest you ask thingspeak's api support. We don't know what changed on their end either.

Comment: Try not to access the api from localhost, but use a proper domain name - and maybe https as well.

Comment: @Bergi can't see anything wrong with using localhost. Also, `http` -> `https` is usually ok (the other way, not so much). It's not very common to run your local dev server over HTTPS either

Comment: @Phil but the thingspeak server might not like it and not send a cors header for it.

Comment: are there any code i can add in my html or javascript, i read about adding allow-access-control-origin on header but my knowledge in pretty basic, im thinking of the <head> in html

Comment: Can you link to the Thingspeak API documentation, I'm finding it difficult to locate. Cursory searches indicate that it supports JSONP if a true CORS option is not available

Comment: Their web server needs to return a proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin. It doesn't even work from thingspeak.com. There's nothing you can do on your end short of setting up a proxy server. @Phil , apparently JSONP is deprecated https://community.thingspeak.com/forum/announcements/jsonp-requests-callback-parameter-are-deprecated/